# Can I declare a directive within a module and use it only within components in that module?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-module

My Angular (v7) app consists of several modules. I have an `AppModule` that contains the core parts of the app, and several separate modules that provide rarely-used parts of the app. (I'm **not** loading these other modules lazily yet, but probably will in the future).

Within one of these modules (let's call it `OtherModule`), I have both components and directives. The directives are *only* used by the components in `OtherModule`. It makes sense (to me) to keep the definition of those directives "encapsulated" within `OtherModule`.

However, when I try to use one of the components from `OtherModule`, I get an error if that component uses one of the directives from `OtherModule`:

> Property binding appOther not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations

(in this example, `appOther` is the directive defined in `OtherModule`).

You can see all this in action (or not) [in this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-paivvz).

I've tried declaring the directive within `AppModule`, but (a) I don't really want to pollute that module with private details of how `OtherModule` works, and (b) it then complains that the directive is declared twice.

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like an obvious requirement (and if this separation of concerns isn't possible, then why do we have modules at all?).

Comment: It appears to work with `<p appOther>` (after removing the `*`). See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2mugug).

Comment: @ConnorsFan: I *looks* like it works, but actually all that's happened is that it no longer recognizes the attribute as a directive. Try changing the directive name to spellingMistake and it makes no difference in your stackblitz.

Comment: Try the stackblitz again. I don't know what made you think that it did not work, since the original directive did nothing.

Comment: @JanRecker: I'm not sure if that's addressed to me or to ConnorsFan. I'm aware of that - and in fact I'm basically following the advice for creating a structural directive here: https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#write-a-structural-directive where the asterisk is used.

Comment: @ConnorsFan: wow. I'm glad (and grateful) you got it to work, although I'm confused as to why. Playing with your stackblitz, it seems that you can include the asterisk or not, and include the value or not **but not both** which is what I had. Weird. Anyway, it seems it's nothing to do with the modules at all, which is where I assumed the problem was. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your original syntax would work for a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives), as shown in [this other stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbzk3d) (the directive shows the element when the input value is `false`).

Comment: @ConnorsFan: yes, and in fact the real directive *is* a structural directive just like your example. (Since I thought the problem was with the module layout, I made the directive as simple as possible - masking the actual problem). As it turns out, my issues were simply that I'd mis-named my \@Input binding (omitting the prefix) and that's what Angular was upset about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

taking a look at your implementation I think that you have to remove de * and the ="true" and leave only the selector appOther

Just like that:

```
<p appOther>
```

The module declaration is OK, you are declaring properly the directive in OtherModule and not exporting them, you can't to declare it in AppModule too. If in other situation you want to share that directive, you should declare it in a shared module which will

Comment: Thanks. This is also what ConnorsFan suggested - and actually it seems that \*appOther and appOther="true" both work, but **not** \*appOther="true". Anyway, the main point is that *it's nothing to do with the modules* which is what I was hung up on.

Comment: Great @Gary McGill, glad to know that now it's working, and yes it seems that one of them works but not both together. But yes, the main point is that, that's why I included the second paragraph ;)